# JAX-RS client sending an array of bytes in a PUT request

Tags: java, ruby, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I've been banging my head against the wall with coding up a JAX-RS client for uploading a file to a Red Hat Satellite Six server.  The REST API for the server specifies what appears to be a somewhat unusual method of uploading the file.  The calling pattern specifies that I create an upload request and then use a PUT to a URL incorporating the id for the upload request (as part of the URL) and two parameters in the body: bytes from the file and an offset for where in the file those bytes belong.  The intention is that callers would read in a file and send chunks of data to the server, which it will then re-assemble when a final call is invoked to commit the upload.

I've found a working Ruby client that implements the basic algorithm and I've confirmed it manipulates the API properly to get the file uploaded.  The sequence of steps is basically what I have in my Java code:  issue an API call to get an upload request id, then enter a loop to read in some bytes and PUT them to the upload URL.  I've tcpdumped the client and see the following request (slightly truncated and cleaned up for readability):

```
PUT /katello/api/repositories/90/content_uploads/ee9028cf-bed6-40fb8561f91a86b95bdc HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;version=2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Language: en
Multipart: true
Content-Length: 8643
User-Agent: Ruby
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXX==
Host: mysathost.example.com

offset=0&content=%ED%AB%EE%DB%03%00%00%00%00%FFhelloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT20150319153318%00%00%00%00% ...snip...
```

My JAX-RS Client's request looks like this:

```
PUT /katello/api/v2/repositories/90/content_uploads/ff4a4273-0b3f-49f0-8e61-223259e09f01 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXX==
User-Agent: Jersey/2.13 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_40)
Host: mysathost.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13567

offset=0&content=%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%03%00%00%00%00%EF%BF%BDhelloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT20150319153318%00%00%00%00 ...snip...
```

There are some obvious differences between the two. The most obvious is that the functioning Ruby client has a "Multipart: true" header that my client doesn't have. The Content-Length is different, possibly because the Ruby client is gzipping the request. Finally, it is obvious that the bytes for my file are being displayed differently between the two even though I'm using the same test file.

I have tried using the Multipart form and provider for Jersey but the raw requests don't seem like Multipart requests and I can't seem to find an Entity that has a way to natively send byte arrays (e.g. with a method that has byte[] in its signature) but still keep the right Content-Type.

As for the byte array encoding, the Ruby code appears to do a file.read of 4K worth of data at a time and dump the results into a variable and then passes that variable into its REST client machinery where it gets digested in a way that I can't trace. I thought it might be Base64 encoding the bytes (with URL escaping), but when I tried that with Commons Codec, the output of my tcpdumps didn't look remotely like the Ruby client. On the assumption that it is just treating the bytes as a Unicode string, I tried to do the same thing in my Java code. That looks closer to what the Ruby client does, but obviously the bytes don't seem to match exactly in the output and the Satellite Server complains that the file is corrupted when I commit the request. Currently my JAX-RS call looks like this:

```java
WebTarget contentUpload = satServer.path("repositories").path(repoId).path("content_uploads").path(uploadRequestId);
Form uploadForm = new Form();
uploadForm.param("offset", Integer.toString(offset));
// data is a byte[] 
uploadForm.param("content", new String(data));

Response response = contentUpload.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(Entity.form(uploadForm));

if (response.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
    StatusType statusInfo = response.getStatusInfo();
    response.close();
    throw new SatelliteException(
            "Encountered error while uploading offset: " + offset
                    + " for " + uploadRequestId + " : "
                    + statusInfo.getStatusCode() + ": "
                    + statusInfo.getReasonPhrase());

}
```

I have tried *new String(data,"UTF-8")* as well with no luck. I have also tried Commons Codec Base64 encoding with URL safety enabled.  I have also tried a multipart/form, but the working request doesn't really seem to follow that pattern.

I'm looking for some idea of how to encode my bytes to match the working client or maybe some sort of Jersey media processing that can handle sending a byte array in a regular form. Or another suggestion about what I should be looking at.  I'm not afraid to do some more digging if I can be pointed in a direction, but I feel I've exhausted what I can learn from the implementation of the Ruby client and server for the moment.  It appears that receiving server is using Apipie and Ruby for its implementation, if that helps.